# Install Python and Django - WHERE?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have read tons of how-to install and watched several You-tubes regarding this matter. And they are all great, but none of the tells me as complete newbie how Python/Django works.

> The first question is: Where should I install what? On my client computer  (Mac) or my server (Debian)? Or both?
>
> Second question: What is Django? A server or an app? The word framework tells me nothing how it works.
>
> Third question: And many instructions assume that you want to use Apache. What if I want to use nginx? Possible?

My guess is that the Apache/nginx load the Python language at startup? And is used by Django in some way?

Apologize if this dumb question have been asked before, but I have not found any clue anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python, django, and apache/nginx should be installed on the server.

Optionally, and ideally, python and django should be installed on your development computer as you create the site. This will then allow you to test it as you develop. No need for apache/nginx on the client/development machine because django can run its own local test server for that

Neither python nor django need to be installed on client computers

Django allows you to build out the server side back end for your website. HTML/Javascript/CSS will allow you to develop the front end (what the user sees and interacts with when they visit the site), but django handles everything on the server side. So heavy computation is handled there, connecting to databases, storing/retrieving database information, routing between the different pages of your website etc.

Python can actually handle all of those things, so technically you don't need django, but the reason it exists is to provide a unified "framework", or way to more easily, compactly and efficiently do all of the above

Yes you can use django with nginx. Something like this would work: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

To answer your final question at a high level: your server has python installed. A django instance is created and run on a specific port (that you specify), which uses that python install. Ultimately, this gives the server/local machine the ability to access your django app/website. But in the real world, you want other users to be able to access your app/site too. This is where a web server like apache or nginx come in. They provide a way for the outside world to access your django instance

You will also need something called a wsgi server. The link I provided above uses uwsgi, and alternative to that is gunicorn. The other answer provided here gives you a good idea of what that does, but it essentially sits between django and nginx/apache/your webserver and passes the information between the two

So what you need on your server: python, django, wsgi server (uwsgi, gunicorn), web server (nginx, apache).
The client does not need any of those things
A development machine only needs python and django (Which runs its own test server)

Comment: What about an App Server?

Comment: Just added an answer to that above

Comment: Added a brief explanation of that. You do need a wsgi server, whether that'd be uwsgi or gunicorn (or others) is up to you

Comment: And posgresql? So I need at least 3 servers running. Nginx, Gunicorn and Posgresql?

Comment: writing/reading from a database, like postgresql, is handled by django. Yes you need all 3, plus you need to make sure your django instance is running too otherwise nothing will work

Comment: "your django instance is running". If Django not is an application what makes the "Django instance" running then?

Comment: I simply meant you need to have django installed on your server along with the others. If you're wanting to set this whole thing up nginx, gunicorn, postgresql, take a look at this, it walks you through everything: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: Thank you! I am beginning to understand now. Start with a local installation to test (Django + Python) and install att server in production (Django+Gunicorn+Nginx).

Comment: If mentioning Apache, you should really be mentioning mod_wsgi. It existed before uWSGI and gunicorn and is still regarded widely as the most stable WSGI deployment method there is.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions one by one:

```
1) Where do I install what
```

You should have a `server` machine, which you can get from one of the hostage providers like Amazon, DigitalOcean, e.t.c. The Web Server ( Apache/Nginx), App Server( Gunicorn) and Django have to be installed in the server machine, along with the db plugins or other packages you need for the site to run.

The client need not have anything but a Browser, to access the app through a URL.

```
2) Is Django an app or a server
```

It's neither. Django is a Web-Framework which helps easier creation of efficient and Robust web applications. As a part of the framework, it also provides a test server, which we run through the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This test server cannot be used while you are running the app in production, for the reasons that:

1) If there are any errors occuring, the entire trace of what the error is, is shown in the client's browser, which exposes critical data.

2) The test server has a log of all requests received, all communications with the database, e.t.c, which may waste too much of space in a production environment.

```
3) Can I use Nginx:
```

Yes you absolutely can use Nginx.

And to give you a brief layout of how Nginx and Django communicate:

1) Nginx is called a Web server. This web server listens to the port 80 by default, for HTTP Requests. 
Say we make a request for myexample.com

2) We have a config file for each domain that this machine hosts, at the folder:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Here we specify where the server should look for when the request comes for that particular domain. Now if the site contains only normal HTML, CSs pages, we specify the path that leads to the index file of that domain. Since ours is a django app, we have to specify the port in which our `Application Server` runs.

3) Gunicorn is the application server, that serves django templates, on request from Nginx. Based on the configuration, Nginx forwards the request to the port that Gunicorn Runs on.

4) Gunicorn calls the specific view, (by URL lookup), gets the view to execute and returns whatever the view returns to Nginx.

5) Nginx returns the data returned by Gunicorn to the client.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Good explanation.

Comment: @sibert Gunicorn communicates only with django.  Django communicate with whatever db you have configured it with

Comment: So Django is a running app or server or what? A bunch of scripts? In order to communicate with Postgresql?

Comment: @sibert Django is a framework.  A django project consists of one or more applications,  which contain the core business logic of the project,  where all the communications happen.  To put in layman terms,  you are right.  It is just a bunch of scripts that communicate with the db

Comment: I really want to accept both answers, they was both helpful and informative. But I cannot accept both so my decision is random.